# Azure ML Studio read from ADLS2 datastore

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azure-data-lake-gen2, ml-studio

I created a datastore in Azure ML Studio that connects to an ADLS Gen2 storage account. I am wondering how can I read data from this datastore in my notebooks in Azure ML Studio? This is what I tried but I am not sure of what the syntax should be. Thanks

```
import pandas as pd

path = "azureml://datastores/[data_store_name]/paths/[path_name]/file.csv"
pd.read_csv("path")
```

Edit:

After adding sub, rg, and workspace, i am getting this error now.

```
----> 9 df = pd.read_csv(path)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py:688, in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    635     engine_specified = False
    637 kwds.update(
    638     delimiter=delimiter,
    639     engine=engine,
   (...)
    685     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines,
    686 )
--> 688 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py:436, in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    430 compression = infer_compression(filepath_or_buffer, compression)
    432 # TODO: get_filepath_or_buffer could return
    433 # Union[FilePathOrBuffer, s3fs.S3File, gcsfs.GCSFile]
    434 # though mypy handling of conditional imports is difficult.
    435 # See https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1297
--> 436 fp_or_buf, _, compression, should_close = get_filepath_or_buffer(
    437     filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression
    438 )
    439 kwds["compression"] = compression
    441 if kwds.get("date_parser", None) is not None:

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py:221, in get_filepath_or_buffer(filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression, mode, storage_options)
    218     pass
    220 try:
--> 221     file_obj = fsspec.open(
    222         filepath_or_buffer, mode=mode or "rb", **(storage_options or {})
    223     ).open()
    224 # GH 34626 Reads from Public Buckets without Credentials needs anon=True
    225 except tuple(err_types_to_retry_with_anon):

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec/core.py:419, in open(urlpath, mode, compression, encoding, errors, protocol, newline, **kwargs)
    369 def open(
    370     urlpath,
    371     mode="rb",
   (...)
    377     **kwargs,
    378 ):
    379     """Given a path or paths, return one ``OpenFile`` object.
    380 
    381     Parameters
   (...)
    417     ``OpenFile`` object.
    418     """
--> 419     return open_files(
    420         urlpath=[urlpath],
    421         mode=mode,
    422         compression=compression,
    423         encoding=encoding,
    424         errors=errors,
    425         protocol=protocol,
    426         newline=newline,
    427         expand=False,
    428         **kwargs,
    429     )[0]

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec/core.py:272, in open_files(urlpath, mode, compression, encoding, errors, name_function, num, protocol, newline, auto_mkdir, expand, **kwargs)
    203 def open_files(
    204     urlpath,
    205     mode="rb",
   (...)
    215     **kwargs,
    216 ):
    217     """Given a path or paths, return a list of ``OpenFile`` objects.
    218 
    219     For writing, a str path must contain the "*" character, which will be filled
   (...)
    270     be used as a single context
    271     """
--> 272     fs, fs_token, paths = get_fs_token_paths(
    273         urlpath,
    274         mode,
    275         num=num,
    276         name_function=name_function,
    277         storage_options=kwargs,
    278         protocol=protocol,
    279         expand=expand,
    280     )
    281     if "r" not in mode and auto_mkdir:
    282         parents = {fs._parent(path) for path in paths}

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec/core.py:574, in get_fs_token_paths(urlpath, mode, num, name_function, storage_options, protocol, expand)
    572 if protocol:
    573     storage_options["protocol"] = protocol
--> 574 chain = _un_chain(urlpath0, storage_options or {})
    575 inkwargs = {}
    576 # Reverse iterate the chain, creating a nested target_* structure

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec/core.py:315, in _un_chain(path, kwargs)
    313 for bit in reversed(bits):
    314     protocol = kwargs.pop("protocol", None) or split_protocol(bit)[0] or "file"
--> 315     cls = get_filesystem_class(protocol)
    316     extra_kwargs = cls._get_kwargs_from_urls(bit)
    317     kws = kwargs.pop(protocol, {})

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec/registry.py:208, in get_filesystem_class(protocol)
    206 if protocol not in registry:
    207     if protocol not in known_implementations:
--> 208         raise ValueError("Protocol not known: %s" % protocol)
    209     bit = known_implementations[protocol]
    210     try:

ValueError: Protocol not known: azureml
```

Comment: What is the error you are facing?

Comment: file path doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

You need to use path like below.

```
"azureml://subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourcegroups/<resourcegroup_name>/workspaces/<workspace_name>/datastores/<datastore_name>/paths/owid-covid-data.csv"
```

code:

```
path = "azureml://subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourcegroups/<resourcegroup_name>/workspaces/<workspace_name>/datastores/<datastore_name>/paths/owid-covid-data.csv"
pd.read_csv(path)
```

[image]

Or one more way to get data in pandas dataframe.

```
pip install adlfs
```

After installing above module, use below code.

```
import  pandas  as  pd
df = pd.read_csv('abfs://<container_name>@<storage_acc_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/csv/owid-covid-data.csv', storage_options = {'connection_string' : 'Your_storage_acc_conn_string'})
df
```

[image]

Like this in `storage_options` you can also give any one of the below.

```
storage_options = {'sas_token' : 'sas_token_value'}
storage_options = {'account_key' : 'account_key_value'}
storage_options = {'tenant_id': 'tenant_id_value', 'client_id' : 'client_id_value', 'client_secret': 'client_secret_value'}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without defining inputting the subscription, rg, and workspace? like have it default to the subscription/rg/workspace where the notebook is being run?

Comment: yes. you need to use those details in uri.

Comment: ok thanks. i ended up getting another error after adding these details. (edit above)

Comment: You executed this one. `pip install adlfs`?

Comment: yes i have this installed

Comment: If your using notebook in ml studio, change your kernal to `Python 3.10 SDK v2`

Comment: Do `pip install azureml-fsspec`. If still error comes.